# How to set field permission with time limit

Tags: entities

I want to set up a customer´s private recording system, where the customer can record his private issues. This record cannot be changed after one hour. The record includes time,episode and my comments. I used "field collection" module to set up the record first, then use "edit limit" module to limit the edit time-everything works fine but I found after one hour, though the customer cannot use the "edit" tab for the whole node, he can still click a "edit" link below each field (time, episode, etc.). Is there anyway to disable the "edit" link for each field after one hour as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide at all links to separately edit/delete field collections values, go to `Structure » Content types » YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE » Manage display`, click to field collection settings cogwheel and clear fields.
[image]

Also you have to forbid an access to edit/delete by direct link, place in your custom module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function yourmodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $path = 'field-collection/' . strtr('your_field_name', array('_' => '-'));
  $items[$path . '/%/edit']['access callback'] = FALSE;
  $items[$path . '/%/delete']['access callback'] = FALSE;
  $items[$path . '/add/*/*']['access callback'] = FALSE;
}
```

Don't forget to clear cache.